# Disable local recipient check in Postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to setup Postfix on CentOS. I have configured it to use my Google apps account to send mails.

Lets say I have configured Postfix to use user1@mydomain.net, which is a Google apps email. I can now successfully make Postfix send an email from user1@mydomain.net to xyz@gmail.com. But when I try to send an email to user2@mydomain.net, I get an error `'Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table'`. i.e. I am unable to send mails to *@mydomain.net which is the domain my Postfix is configured for.

I understand that Postfix checks `local_recipient_maps` and rejects if the local_recipient is not found. Now my question, what is the right setting I need to add to disable this local recipient check?

Relevant links:
[LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README](http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html)
[smtpd_recipient_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions)

Comment: Postfix shouldn't be the destination for mydomain.net if that's a Google Apps account. What exactly are you trying to do with Postfix?

Comment: @mgroven That just stuck me, so I changed mydestination from mydomain.net, its working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By configuring Postfix with mydomain.net as a destination, you are telling it that it is the final endpoint for that domain (and therefore it should try to deliver it locally). If this domain is hosted at Google Apps it should not be specified as a destination for Postfix.